# Can I drill extra holes into an Ikea Trotten table top so that I can connect it to a Rudolf underframe?

Tags: table, particle-board

This is the Rudolf (https://www.ikea.com/in/en/p/rodulf-underframe-sit-stand-f-table-top-white-10497373/) and this is the Trotten table top(https://www.ikea.com/in/en/p/trotten-table-top-beige-70474868/). The holes definitely don't line up, but can I drill holes and use the table top anyway?

The Trotten is made of particleboard and melamine foil according to the website. So I'm not sure if the wood will hold up or crumble or if I need an extra female screw receptor.

Comment: How close to the existing Trotten mounting holes would you need to drill the new ones for Rudolf? Many IKEA table tops only have solid areas strong enough to be able to drill and screw into in certain areas where their designers intend for the legs to be mounted, and hollow space everywhere else.

Answer (score 2):

Can you? Yes.

Will it work? Possibly.

I purchased an IKEA desktop and a different set of legs than was designed to go with it.  I drilled new holes in the top to match the holes in the legs and bolted the whole thing together. The legs are adjustable for height and I've cranked it up and down numerous times over the last 2.5-3 years with no issue.

**HOWEVER** as noted in [brhans' comment](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/247378/can-i-drill-extra-holes-into-an-ikea-trotten-table-top-so-that-i-can-connect-it#comment487136_247378) and confirmed by this text from your table top link:

> ...particle board with a slice of wood as top layer *instead of solid wood* only in this product...
> <sup>emphasis added</sup>

I had to be *very* careful about where I drilled my holes because the desktop is hollow core with about a 2" band of solid wood around the edges. I had several things to consider as I made my new holes:

- All of my holes had to be into the solid wood at the edge
- My holes couldn't go too deep or I would have drilled right through the top, ruining it
- Because of the manual crank handle, I had to drill two holes that were not and could not be in the solid edge.

  - I drilled these very carefully, since once I penetrated the surface layer, there was basically nothing to stop the drill bit from flying through the hollow space and hitting the other surface, possibly punching right through the top.
  - I drilled my pilot holes for these *very* small to minimize the effort necessary to drive the screw and to maximize the amount of material left for the screw to bite into.
  - I drove the screw very carefully and slowly to ensure it bit into the surface and didn't just spin since there is very little for it to hold on to and it could easily strip out the hole.
  - Fortunately, these two holes are for a clip that holds the crank handle and they take very little weight and are *not* important to the top coming off of the base. If they do strip out, a clip falls off, but the desk won't collapse.

---

You will have to very carefully determine how wide the band of "solid" wood (particle board) is for *your* top - it may be different than mine. I would suspect that IKEA is working to make this solid edge as small as possible since that uses the least amount of (relatively) expensive particle board and maximized the (relatively) cheap honeycomb material filling in the rest of the desk. My guess is that the particle board edge is only big enough to support the legs that are "supposed" to go with the top.

I would recommend looking at and measuring (if possible) the legs that are "supposed" to go with this top as it will give you an idea of where the solid edge band actually is. The pre-drilled holes in the bottom of the desk will also give you an idea of where there is solid wood.

#### Disclaimer:

Once you start drilling new holes in the top it is *highly* unlikely that IKEA will accept the item for return. You're on your own from here.

Yes, I did it and yes it has successfully held up for me. I've done woodworking, cabinetry and construction and have nearly 30 years of home DIY experience under my belt. I consider myself reasonably handy with tools, and I'm a very detail oriented person.

*You* will have to consider *your* skills and abilities with tools to determine if *you* are capable of doing this yourself. If you're unsure, find a friend or family member who may be able to guide you.

Comment: At only 2cm thick and nearly 39lbs, the linked tabletop probably doesn’t have hollow spots.

Comment: I wouldn't be so sure of that, @nobody, particle board is heavy stuff. That's another reason they try to minimize its use - it's heavy to ship.

Comment: @FreeMan are you contradicting him or agreeing with him? Ikea claims the TROTTEN is made of particleboard, which, given the weight, should be solid, without hollow spots. Compared to the LINNMON (google linnmon teardown), which has the hollow honeycomb cardboard throughout the majority of the desk top, and only particleboard at the ends for leg attachments.